# Is it possible to disable the kudu scm

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

Disable kudu for the running web app.
Why? Kudu is consuming the CPU periodically and I want to stop that.

So far I have tried to Kill the process by clicking on Properties >> Kill button. but this process gets start again.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Comment: @Jason Pan: I have app service plan (isolated), with 2 instances, when i look in metrics for CPU utilization graph, I saw few spikes in it. but after splitting it with instances, CPU utilization spike only for 1 instance and not for other. Don't know why. When I diagnose it I thought its kudu process which is causing spike. so want to disable it. but that was not the case. Still lookin in it.

Comment: You can try this method of mine, if not works, I will try to find another way to help you.

Comment: @Jason Pan : I guess you forgot to provide the link

Comment: I have post my answer, you can check it.

Comment: Use below settings in `Application settings`, main site and scm site will  run in different sandboxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below settings in `Application settings`.

> When separation enabled (the default), the main site and scm site run in different sandboxes.

```
WEBSITE_DISABLE_SCM_SEPARATION=true
```

[image]

Then you can check Process Explorer.

[image]

## Offical Doc:

[image]

[Use the same process for the user site and the scm site](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#use-the-same-process-for-the-user-site-and-the-scm-site)